# Color Excel rows if certain conditions apply using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to make a macro to color excel rows if certain conditions apply, however, when I run it I get a syntax error in this line:

```
If (Not item1 (Cells(matchline, 1)) Then GoTo continue
```

Also, I'd like for a certain range to be colored, not the entire row. I have this from another macro, but don't know how to apply it correctly in ColorRows:

```
Range(Cells(Rng.row, "A"), Cells(Rng.row, "M")).Interior.Color = xlNone
```

Current code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorRows()


    Dim matchline As Integer, lastmatchline As Integer, lastbinline As Integer
    Dim item1 As String, line As Integer, endline As Integer

    'For line = 3 To endline

    For matchline = 6 To lastmatchline

        item1 = Cells(matchline, 1).Value

        If (Not item1 (Cells(matchline, 1)) Then GoTo continue

        If Not item1(Cells(matchline, 1)) Then GoTo continue

        If (item1 = "Unexpected Status") Then _
        Cells(matchline, 1).EntireRow.Font.Interior.Color = 13434828

        If (item1 = "At Risk") Then _
        Cells(matchlineline, 1).EntireRow.Font.Interior.Color = 8420607

        If (item1 = "Requirements Definition") Then _
        Cells(matchlineline, 1).EntireRow.Font.Interior.Color = 10092543

continue:
    Next line
End Sub
```

Comment: That is definitely incorrect syntax but, not knowing what you are trying to test in that line, it is a bit hard to suggest what you should change it to.

Comment: Should your Next also be Next matchline?

Comment: ^^ or just `Next`

Comment: And lastmatchline is initialised as 0 but you are not stepping backwards (e.g. step -1) so how are you going from 6 to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rows As Long, i As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range, rngColor As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set ws = ActiveSheet

rows = ws.UsedRange.rows.Count

For i = 1 To rows
    Set rngSearch = ws.Cells(i, 1)
    Set rngColor = ws.Range("A" & i, "M" & i)

    If rngSearch = "Unexpected Status" Then
        rngColor.Interior.Color = 13434828
    End If
    If rngSearch = "At Risk" Then
        rngColor.Interior.Color = 8420607
    End If
    If rngSearch = "Requirements Definition" Then
        rngColor.Interior.Color = 10092543
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, thanks for your tip. It worked! However, I'd like for the cells to be colored, not the font. I tried to change your suggestion to this:

rngColor.Font.Interior.Color

But then it no longer worked. Hope you can help

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the change. Change Font.Color to Interior.Color.